# How can I sort a linked list of objects based on two of the objects parameters?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I am using a linked list to represent a sparse matrix where the linked list holds only the non-zero elements along with their row and column in the matrix, in order to not waste memory.

I need to be able to display these elements with there location in order based on their row then column.  For example the matrix holding {data 5, row 2, col 0}, {data 8, row 0, col 2}, {data 1, row 0, col 1} would print out:

0 1 1, 0 2 8, 2 0 5.

The matrix is written as:

```
LinkedList<MatrixElement> matrix = new LinkedList<MatrixElement>();
```

And the element class is written as:

```
class MatrixElement {  //Data object for each node in list, holds value and location

private int data;
private int row;
private int col;

public MatrixElement(int row, int col, int data){
    this.data = data;
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;
}

public int getData(){
    return data;
}

public int getRow(){
    return row;
}

public int getCol(){
    return col;
```

Any feedback on how I should go about sorting this in order to ultimately print it would be appreciated. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Take a look into [`List.sort(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-)

Answer (score 4):

You can sort by row then column like this:

```
matrix.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(MatrixElement::getRow) 
                      .thenComparingInt(MatrixElement::getCol));
```

Comment: Hi! The jdk team changed sorting algortihms, so now the List interface copies the contents of the list to an array, sorts the array, and changes every node contents from the array, this is why complexity remains O(nlogn)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider implementing `Comparable` interface in `MatrixElement` class. Also, it's worth considering to override `toString()` method of this class, to make it print results in more readable way. Look how you could achieve that:

```
class MatrixElement implements Comparable<MatrixElement> {

    //fields, constructor and getters...

    public String toString() {
        return "[row:" + this.getRow() + ", col:" + this.getCol() + ", data:" + this.getData() + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MatrixElement me) {
        if(this.getRow() < me.getRow()) {
            return -1;
        } else if(this.getRow() > me.getRow()) {
            return 1;
        } // if getRow() is equal to both, proceed with comparing columns...
        if(this.getCol() < me.getCol()) {
            return -1;
        } else if(this.getCol() > me.getCol()) {
            return 1;
        } // if getCol() is equal to both, it returns 0
        return 0;
    }
}
```

After implementing `compareTo()` method, when using `Collections.sort()` method, order provided in `compareTo()` method is used:

```
List<MatrixElement> elements = new ArrayList<>();
elements.add(new MatrixElement(5,2,0));
elements.add(new MatrixElement(8,0,2));
elements.add(new MatrixElement(1,0,1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elements.toArray()));
Collections.sort(elements);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elements.toArray()));
```

Output you get:

```
[[row:5, col:2, data:0], [row:8, col:0, data:2], [row:1, col:0, data:1]]
[[row:1, col:0, data:1], [row:5, col:2, data:0], [row:8, col:0, data:2]]
```